# I live in Hawai'i where houses generally have both cockroaches and geckos. Are the geckos being poisoned by the poisoned roaches?

Tags: safety, geckos

My apartment (and most like it here in the heart of Honolulu) has german cockroaches. While I'm sure that we'll never get rid of them completely, poison traps (roach hotels) and raid barrier poison as well as being squeaky clean keeps them basically out of our sight. My biggest concern is the geckos that show up in the house periodically. I know they eat roaches. If they eat a roach that has been poisoned (which all of the roaches in my house have been because I spread that stuff everywhere, even behind the fridge, stove, and cabinets), how much is it hurting them? What we're using Combat brand roach hotels and Raid spray as well as Raid border control.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of poison you use. I don't know how hard it would be to get in Hawaii, but diatomaceous earth would be an excellent solution. It's basically a white looking powder. Supposedly, it's like microscopically sharp glass blades. It's too small to harm even the gecko (I've even been told it won't harm earth worms). The way it's effective is that it slices into the exoskeleton of insects and they dehydrate and die.

I've read that people feed it to their animals and sometimes take it themselves with no ill effect. Supposedly it treats intestinal parasites. Either way, you can put this powder out and when the cockroaches move through it, it should damage them and they should die. The geckos could eat it with no real effect and it won't hurt you either, so you can put it in your cabinets with your dishes or anywhere you want. It shouldn't be harmful to children, pets, people, or other small animals. Only insects with their hard exoskeletons.

Comment: bump for DE, hadnt heard of it before now. I wonder if this can be used to get rid of mites on snakes

Comment: I can't answer that as I've never heard one way or the other, but I don't see why not. I have no idea how much contact is required, but I feel like you could probably put some in a duster and just powder your snake down, then rinse him off after a little while. If you can spot the mites, maybe you can spot test it.

Comment: Hmm if i ever get mites i may try that to see.